# JavaFX How to add border radius to a pane with background image

Tags: javafx

I am working on a JavaFX application and I want to add a background image to a pane while also giving it rounded corners. However, when I apply the CSS properties to add the border radius to the pane, it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have tried so far:

```java
Pane pane = new Pane();
BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(new Image("background.png"), BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
pane.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 10;");
```

The background image appears just fine, but the border radius doesn't seem to have any effect on the pane. I have also tried using `-fx-background-clip: content-box;` but that didn't work either.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve the desired result of having a rounded corner pane with a background image in JavaFX? Thank you in advance!